# Max height not working with percentage when inside 'position: fixed'

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a pop up dialog with a list of items in it. I am trying to give the list of items a max-height relative to the overall height of the screen.

After some fiddling with the styles, it seems to me like it doesn't work when pop up dialog have max-height because it creates a cycle in the computation: The popup dialog's height depends on the height on the list of items, and the list of items max-height's depends on the popup dialog's height.

Please see the attached plunkr for an example: when #popup-container has max-height of 66%, the list of items (popup-content) has no max-height.

http://plnkr.co/edit/esdIMjvOgJ8hRM8mSk2t?p=preview

Comment: I can't see anything at the plunkr link. But anyway, yes, if something doesn't have a height (even if it does have a min-height or a max-height), its children can't have relative heights in percentages.

Comment: I think you want to start by moving your overflow:auto; to your container, since thats where the max-height is. This won't solve your entire issue, i just noticed

Answer (score 0):

this seems to do the trick:
Entire CSS page:

```
/* Styles go here */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#popup-container {
  position:fixed;
  max-height: 66%; 
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 500px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

.popup-footer , .popup-header {
  display: block;
  background: #ccc;
  height: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 480px;
}
.popup-footer{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

The footer is a bit hacky though... i'm not sure yet how to work around that one.
I gave the header/footer a width so it doesnt go over the scrollbar :S

Comment: Nevermind, the footer can be 'fixed at bottom 0' because the container is already at 'fixed and bottom 0' i guess.